# Powershell Get-Job file name or extension is too long

Tags: powershell, asynchronous

I have a PS script that collects server metrics. It works absolutely fine when I run it as a single threaded. However when I set it up to run multi threaded, I receieve the below error.

```
An error occurred while starting the background process. Error reported: The filename or extension is too long.

$jobs=$serverList|%{ Start-Job -InitializationScript $functions -ArgumentList $_ -ScriptBlock {
Script Line-1
Script Line-2
Script Line-3
Script Line-4
Script Line-5
Script Line-6
Script Line-7
}
```

`$functions` has 10 functions,totaling about 350 lines.

Based on the research that I have done this error comes up because the initialization script has too many lines of script.Let me know how do I fix this without truncating any script.

First Update-
I was able to resolve the issue by reducing the size of the scriptblock. Based on this [Site](http://systemcentersynergy.com/max-script-block-size-when-passing-to-powershell-exe-or-invoke-command/) we can only have about 12 bytes of data being sent in script block. Pretty weird issue. Any solution on how to overcome this size limitations.

For now the issue is resolved by removing unwanted spaces and additonal logs written. However if there is a need to modify the script further this solution may not hold good. Looking forward for few suggestions.

Comment: Check option 3 on this page: https://www.itdroplets.com/run-a-command-as-a-different-user-in-powershell/. It seems that it is just because it starts the session with a long default location. Maybe you can use `Start-Process` with the `-WorkingDirectory $env:windir` argument instead of `Start-Job`?

Comment: @Kluk That is not an option for me since these are prod servers and I do not have the required access to do it. Also the clone of the same script is working fine since it has lesser `$functions` and no of lines of code.

Comment: Try this: create a dedicated .ps1 script file containing all the commands. Copy it to remote server. Use Start-Job to run the big script file. Would that work?

Comment: @vonPryz Thats a no-go. Since I have over 70 odd servers to collect details from.

Comment: Put the script on a SMB share and invoke it from each server via UNC path. But that's kind besides of the point, if you don't know if running a script file from job has the same problem than running the scriptblock version.

Comment: Well the script works fine when I execute it without the script block. Is there any solution that can be implemented without modifying any other server? And making some changes to the existing script?

Comment: Why not dot source the functions into scope?

Comment: @DougMaurer Thanks for the suggestion. i have updated the question with the partial solution.